# We know that a Compact set is closed. However a finite discreet set is compact but not closed (contradicting the theorem?)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

We know that a Compact set is closed. We also know that a finite discreet set is compact  (as every cover has a finite sub cover). However a finite discreet set is not closed (contradicting the theorem?). I am sure I am missing something here, or the theorem has certain conditions embedded.

Comment: What topological space are you working with? Why do you say that a finite discrete set is not closed?

Comment: The metric space can be Euclidean space. A finite discrete set is not closed as it doesn't have all its limit points. A finite discrete set in R can be {1,2,3}.

Comment: Note that discreet is a real word too, but the topology word is discrete.

Comment: @YanMu : Every finite discrete set in Euclidean space is closed, since it does contain all of its limit points.  It contains all of its limit points because it has no limit points.

Comment: Yan Mu: The set $\{1,2,3\}$ has no limit points, therefore it contains all of them.

Comment: Clearly you are correct. Thanks a lot and sorry for being naive.

Comment: In $\mathbb {R} $, a finite set cannot have a limit point. All points should be isolated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a metric space, the following two things are true: any compact set is closed, and any finite set is both closed and compact.

Your statement that a finite set might not be closed is not true for metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A finite discrete set *is* closed.